# Tag based syntax highlighting isn't working in all the questions

Tags: bug, status-completed

For those who don't know, SE uses Google Prettify to [automatically add syntax highlighting to any code](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) posted based on the tags applied in the question.

If we specify `<!-- language : lang-language_code -->`, syntax highlighting seems to be working fine.

However, if we don't specify it, then the codes should be highlighted based on tags applied on the question. This doesn't seem to be the case everywhere. For example:

- [cant locate FILE/Find.pm in @INC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214116/cant-locate-file-find-pm-in-inc) - [perl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/perl)
- [Where is my glut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404282/where-is-my-glut) - [c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/c)
- [My ubuntu can't kill the process which occupy too much memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397670/my-ubuntu-cant-kill-the-process-which-occupy-too-much-memory) - [c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/c)
- [Header files in Anjuta](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388715/header-files-in-anjuta) - [c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/c)

The problem seems to be specific to some tags only, as most of the [python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python) based questions seem to have syntax highlighting applied based on tags.

Comment: Reproducible in Chromium and Iceweasel.

Comment: Don't forget [tag:java].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those binding are not automatic, they have to be setup explicitly for each tag by a moderator.

I've configured the [c](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/c), [java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/java) and [perl](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/perl).

Turn to [askubuntu moderators](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) for [support](/questions/tagged/support) for other languages that need syntax highlighting.

Comment: What is the preferred [way to contact moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49834/217657)? Flagging a question where it’s applicable? Specifically, I’d like to add the highlight support for [tag:csh] and [tag:php].

Comment: @csh yes that, or ask a question describing what you want on meta (here) and tag it with [meta-tag:support]